# How does iPhone restore so fast?

Tags: iphone, ios, backup, restore

Yesterday, I restored my iPhone in DFU mode. I think iOS is built from source in this mode and there is no way to access old data. My backup size was around 3 GB. Even though my internet speed is fast. Downloading the backup took 1 minute but the actual installation of backup only took under 10 seconds.

I wonder how is backup restored so fast?

I would like to know how the installation of backup works for iOS.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way 3 GB is transferred under 10 secs. It would need >300 MB/s speed. Most probably your backup was already there.

Comment: And remember, 300MBps is 2400Mbps, which is the more normal way to measure network speed.

Comment: Sorry for not putting it correctly. The download did take a minute but the installation took only 10 seconds, also it is an iPhone 5s so not very high processing power. I wanted to know about the installation process of backup.

Comment: @SohelShaikh Just a simple reboot takes that long. You must be missing something.